# how to implement rate limiting functionality in spring boot embedded web servers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, webserver, rate-limiting

I read that spring boot has embedded web servers.

But after going through [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html) on embedded servers and exploring tens of articles, I am not able to find documentation which can help me in developing rate limiting functionality using spring boot embedded web servers.

Looking at lack of resources, I am confused now. So putting my question here.

Is it possible to  implement rate limiting functionality using spring boot embedded web servers. Any leads on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this answer will be useful for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042412/how-to-set-rate-limit-for-each-user-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such funcionality out of the box. You can implement it by yourself, for example by using Filters:

```
public class LimitFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //do check if limit is reached
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```