# How to set rate limit for user specific in springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have some issue with rate limit concept, I have tried to create one POC where we are blocking the no of request based on time and its working fine.
But i need to imeplement rate limit based on user to user like, In my appication differnt user can search the product parallely if i am imeplenting rate limit then its blocking for all users not for single user.
Any one can help here..

I have craeted the POC for rate limit and i can see its applicable for all users.
Lets example as below:
1.Suppose for my application i keep 5 request per minute , For 6th request it will block and give error mesage .
2.But what about for the other user,He is not searched yet and when he will try to serach he will also get the same exception

Answer (score 0):

First of all your implementation sounds to point as it is doing what is expected out of rate-limiting features.

The only part in which you are falling behind in is implementing this feature on a user basis which can be done basis on an identifier upon which we can separate out every user.

In a general use case, one can have a **username+sessionid** as a unique identifier to implement rate limiting on the user level which will solve your issue.

You can use a database or cache to understand or keep track of current hits being done to the server and then compare it with the rate-limiting logic you have in place.

Being said that this is a very requirement-specific implementation but I hope I gave you a starting point to work upon.

Comment: Hi Suchndra,
Thanks for the valuable suggestion, Could you plz send me the sample code to implement using username+sessionid.

Comment: Sure, this is nicely explained with all the code over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042412/how-to-set-rate-limit-for-each-user-in-spring-boot

This beautifully works at the IP level which is one of the user identifiers.
Please accept the answer if this helped you in your current task.

Comment: Yes i have tried this code in my application, BUt whats the problem is Imy application for all user i am getting same Ipaddress so its very difficult to identify the user to whom i need to block it.Example: Ehen i am trying to acces to access commmon server it will always give the same ipaddress to all user.

Comment: So Nihar if you go through carefully. X-Forwarded-For is like an IP of the last hop of request. by any chance your application is running behind proxy?

Comment: Yes it running based on proxy address.

Comment: Thats why its not possible based on ip adress, Because it will always create the same ipaddress for all user.

Comment: Is there any alternate way instead of Ipadress? I have already tested with Ipaddress for my case Ipadress is not the proper way to handle my scenario.

Comment: Nihar so ip address is just one unique identifier. What does your request look like? do we have any client-related info which we send along with the request or more specifically any unique header in the request?

Comment: No,I have checked that also there is no unique identifier in the request.